# ATAN2() function in Tableau custom query

Tags: tableau-api

I want to calculate ATAN2(X,Y) in Tableau Custom Query where I have connected CSV using legacy connection. However I get error "Undefined function 'ATAN2'". Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you need to create an extract of your data before you can use this function. Let me know if that solves it.

[image]